# Handle exception as a parse error in bison

Tags: c++, exception, bison

How do i catch en exception thrown upon executing a rule in bison like

```
foo : BAR { $$ = new Bar($1); }
```

The Bar constructor throws `std::invalid_argument` exception if it's argument is inappropriate. I would like to catch that exception and raise a compilation error, so I get native error message like

```
input:42.10: Bad value `baz' for bar
```

Also there are a lot of this kind of rules, so It would be great to handle that not within rule itself, but somewhere in the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `lalr1.cc`, the C++ skeleton of Bison, then there is some limited support for exceptions: if you throw a `yy::parser::syntax_error`, then the exception is caught as a syntax error, duly reported, and the parser enters the error recovery mode.  That's very much like using `YYERROR`.

If you throw anything else, the whole parsing is aborted, the stack is cleaned, and the exception is rethrown.  That's `YYABORT`.

So if you'd like to errors caught as rule-reduction you should throw the specific exception, see [C++ Parser Interface Documentation of Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-syntax_005ferror).